# How do I get touch tracks working in Logic Pro X?

Tags: software, daw, logic-pro

In my Logic Pro X file, I have created a Touch Tracks layer in the environment. I have also assigned a track in the arrange window for Touch Tracks. Also, I assigned midi loops to the touch track keyboard. However, when I try to play the touch tracks through a midi keyboard, no sounds are generated. Can someone explain why this is happening?[image: This is my Environment Window]

This is my environment window for the touch tracks

[image]

This is the touch tracks midi assigning

[image]

And this is what I'm getting

Answer (score 1):

First, be sure Logic is *playing* - no sounds will be generated from Touch Tracks (TT) unless Logic is in play mode...

While Logic is in play mode, are you able to mouse click B2, C3, or D3 on the TT keyboard to generate sound?
Note that having Toggle/Gate set means that MIDI region will only trigger one time per playback.

Also, your Musical Typing keyboard is grayed out, which means your TT track is not selected and/or armed (R). Also be sure you're MT keyboard is set to the correct octave in order to play B2, C3 or D3. Use the MIDI status to see what note is being triggered at top of Logic Window.

And, I can't find any reason why you would have cables going from the TT object to MIDI object.

**Touch Tracks Primer (Logic Pro X 10.1)**

```
1. Window->Open MIDI Environment
2. From this environment window: New->Touch Tracks. The TT Environment Window will open.
   Move it aside for now.
3. In arrangement window:
    Create new and/or select unused track and reassign to (Touch Tracks)
    via right click->Reassign Track->Mixer->(Touch Tracks)
    This track must be armed (R) for TT to play
3. Assign Content
    Only folders and MIDI regions! No audio regions.
    Drag a Green loop from loop browser to arrange window to create *new* track - this
    is where the content will play from, so it can be tweaked normally.
    Drag the region from this new track to an unused slot in the Touch Tracks
    environment window (the one with the keyboard on the left). The slot will light up
    when it's able to accept your drag.
4. Repeat until you've loaded up all your content.
5. Move playhead beyond last region in arrangement window, be sure (Touch Tracks)
   is armed, hit play.
6. Play corresponding MIDI note to trigger the MIDI region.
```

**Have Fun!**